# Java Cross with characters

Tags: java, console, formatting

I managed to make a perfectly even cross with `for` loops.

I'm trying to make this cross easier to code.  I have to keep it with `for` loops, but it's too long to implement.

```
public class CroixDemoAmmeliore {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int e = 5;
        int i;
        int j;
        int k;
        int l;

        for (k = 1; k <= e; k++) {
            for (i = 1; i <= e; i++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (j = 1; j <= e; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for (k = 1; k <= e; k++) {
            for (i = 1; i <= e * 3; i++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for (k = 1; k <= e; k++) {
            for (i = 1; i <= e; i++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (j = 1; j <= e; j++) {
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When i formatted your code, i saw that `int l` is unused. Is that intentional, or it might be something problematic?

Comment: Oops, no that's just a mistake that does not change the result of the code. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You misspelled _Amélioré_ with an extra _m_. Incidentally, Java allows [non-ASCII characters in identifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8), though in practice using such characters would probably cause problems with filesystems, version control tools, and other programmers.

Answer (score 2):

First thing I would say is that you could reduce the number of variables you use. The iterator of a For loop, if instanced from outside the loop's context (as in your case), can be reused. Doing so you could already reduce the numbers of variables you use.

I do not understand what you mean by "easier to code", but if you mean that you seek a way to more easily re-use this code, you could either make a static method that would display a cross with specific parameters or an object with a display function.

Here is an exemple of a Cross object:

```
public class Cross {

    private int sectionSize;

    public Cross(int sectionSize) {
        this.sectionSize = sectionSize;
    }

    public void display() {
        final int height = sectionSize * 3;
        final char character = '*';
        //The iterators
        int i, j;

        //This loop controls the line
        for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            //Check wether or not to add spaces
            if (i < sectionSize || i > sectionSize * 2) {
                //Add spaces
                for (j = 0; j < sectionSize; j++)
                    System.out.print(" ");
                //Add the characters
                for (j = 0; j < sectionSize; j++)
                    System.out.print(character);
            }
            else
                for (j = 0; j < height; j++)
                    System.out.print(character);
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Or in the format of a static method (which is actually the display method of the last object without the comments):

```
public static void drawCross(int sectionSize, char character) {
    final int height = sectionSize * 3;
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        if (i < sectionSize || i > sectionSize * 2) {
            for (j = 0; j < sectionSize; j++)
                System.out.print(" ");
            for (j = 0; j < sectionSize; j++)
                System.out.print(character);
        }
        else
            for (j = 0; j < height; j++)
                System.out.print(character);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Here is how you would use either of these solutions:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    final int sectionSize = 5;

    //Use of the Object
    Cross cross = new Cross(sectionSize);
    cross.display();

    //Use of the static method
    Cross.drawCross(sectionSize, '*');
}
```

Now, if it were not for the necessity of using For loops, I would have replaced the loop that adds the space with a simpler:

```
System.out.printf(("%," + sectionSize + "s"), "");
```

and then I would have added the characters of the cross in a loop.
I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

If you view the canvas as a square and hide/show the symbol at the current coordinate accordingly, then the solution can be reduced to two loops.

```
public class Cross {
 private int width;
 private String output;

 public Cross(int size, String output){
   width = size;
   this.output = output;
 }

 public void draw() {

    for(int i = 0; i < width * 3; ++i){
      for(int j = 0; j < width * 3; ++j){
        System.out.print( isPaintable(i) || isPaintable(j) ? output : " ");
      }
      System.out.println("");
    }
 }

 private boolean isPaintable(int x){
    return x >= width && x < width * 2;
 }
}
```

Essentially, the same solution as already provided but with general application of [De Morgan's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) and conversion to ternary statement.

Comment: Since `size` is being used for both the horizontal and vertical axes, I'd keep it named as `size` rather than renaming it to `width`.

Comment: It would be clearer if `output` were called `fill`. It should probably be just a `char`.

Comment: @200_success Valid points.